# Find nGinx Bound Port

Tags: server, nginx, varnish

I'm having a heck of an issue here.
I have nginx & varnish installed.  Configured nginx to listed on port 8080, and varnish to listen on port 80

nGinx will not start due to

`Jul 06 16:26:36 host nginx[2863]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`

I have grep'd my entire server to see if I can find where it could also be "extra" bound, and nothing is found.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/bpnxki

**EDIT:** I have killed the varnish process for now, then restarted nginx, and when I `netstat -tlnp` I can see that it is binding to both ports 80 and 8080.  I need this on port 8080 only: http://prntscr.com/bpo2yl

How can I prevent nginx from binding to port 80 period?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the configurations for your nginx sites under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and change the `listen` directives to a different port. Or remove the sites from the enabled list.  Once done and you run `sudo service nginx restart`, then `nginx` should no longer bind to those ports.

(The only other reason nginx might bind to ports and disobey the standard config is if it's not a standard setup and is, for example, an nginx that is bundled up with some other software and not following the standard configuration locations as a result.)

Comment: I deleted both the sites-enabled and sites-available folders..., and it's a standard ubuntu nginx install. other than my own configurations which i've verified there are `no` port 80 bindings

Comment: besides... wouldn't `grep` find the string I searched for in the first screenshot?

Comment: And you stopped or restarted the nginx service afterwards?

Comment: It wasn't running, and when I started it, that is when the error is thrown

Comment: I would create a configuration then in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` that listens on some bogus port you don't care about then - it's probable that nginx is attempting to bind to a port by default as per the defaults compiled into it.  If you give it a different port to listen on though that may solve the issue.

Comment: Given I am on my phone I can't give you such an example right now, will do at home though after my commute.

Comment: my server does not use `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, however, when I added a `listen 82;`, port 80 shows still bound: http://prntscr.com/bpoknf